# Can I create EventListener in AS3 from one Object and remove it from another Object?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener

I spent lots of time trying to resolve this issue. So, basically I have an class (addadd) that contain function which can create eventListener and remove eventListener. And I have another two objects (Symbol1, Symbol2) that tell the function what to do - create or remove.

---

```
    package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class addadd
{

    var stanishev:stanishev_line = new stanishev_line;

    public function addadd()
    {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function stanishevF(par1)
    {
        if (par1 == "create")
        {
        Main.display.addChild(stanishev);
        stanishev.name = "stanishev_child";
        stanishev.x = -200;
        stanishev.y = 500;
        stanishev.gotoAndPlay("start");
        stanishev.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameDOstanishev);
        }
        else 
        {
            trace ("asasasas");
        stanishev.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameDOstanishev);
        }
    }

    public function frameDOstanishev(e:Event)
    {
        trace (stanishev.currentFrame);
    }
} }    

package {

import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class Symbol1 extends SimpleButton
{

    var call_creator:addadd = new addadd;


    public function Symbol1()
    {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, eventResponse);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, eventResponse2);

    }

    function eventResponse(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        call_creator.stanishevF("create");
    }

    function eventResponse2(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        call_creator.stanishevF("destroy");
    }
} }    

package {


import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class Symbol2 extends SimpleButton
{
    var call_creator:addadd = new addadd;

    public function Symbol2()
    {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, eventResponse2);
    }

    function eventResponse2(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        call_creator.stanishevF("destroy");
    }
} }
```

So I can make addadd class to create and remove this eventListener from Symbol1 but I am not able to make the addadd class to create this eventListener sending "create" parameter from Symbol1 and remove it from Symbol2 by sending "destroy" parameter!!!

How can I create and remove the same eventListener from different objects? I found this approach creating and killing the listeners for more organized but I am not sure if this is the right way. *I am having problems with the listeners (error: 1009) when I move between frames in the main timeline, so I want to kill them all before jump to another frame.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put `public function` say, `removeListeners()` and `addListeners()` in  that class and call those function from other class, like so,

```
 class A ()
 {

      //constructor code


      public function removeListeners():void
      {

            //remove listeners here
      }
  }
```

Then call this `removeListeners()` `public function` from the class(e.g. `Main.as`) where you have created instance of this "A" class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I probably didn't explained properly!
 I have class "creatorRemover" that contains add and remove eventListener and handler function in the same class. So, I also have two different buttons/classes, one to call addListener and the other to call removeListeer Function. The purpose of those buttons are to start and stop Handler function in creatorRemover class to do what it's doing.

Comment: The biggest catch here is that I want to add/remove eventListeners using two different classes, one calls the createRemove class asking to remove and another to add!

Comment: Some help here Please guys!